# Matplotlib: Clickable content in figure + new window

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I've been working with matplotlib on this graph here.
As you can see we got calendar weeks on the x-axis and the amount of supporttickets on the y-axis (sorry for german language on the graph).

Now I want to be able to click a calendar week on the y-axis and it should open a new window where I can see a list of all open tickets from that calendar week.

I have no problems handling my database but I have no clue how to make the calendar weeks "clickable" and how to create a new window from a figure.

Thanks.

[image: my_figure]

Comment: edit: i'm not sure if this is even possible in matplotlib ..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which errors do  you get? If you would show us some sourcecode we can help a lot more

Comment: tbh i'm clueless where to start.

Comment: Give us a reduced part of your current sources that show where your problem is. At least how your Graph is created (axis, plot itself, __not__ your complete script)

Comment: here's a pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/KfpUAkwa) of my plotcode.

Comment: You are asking your question on Stackoverflow , so please follow the guidelines of asking questions. Reduce your code to the least neccessary to describe your problem. This is Stackoverflow - __not__ letmecodethatforyou.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)

You can bind to axis enter event and general click event to check if a click was done inside the axis.